# nginx report upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed）but actually the service received the request

Tags: java, http, nginx, tcp

OS: windows 10

Service type: an HTTP server build by Spring Boot

My scenario is to provide an attachment upload interface, the attachment is uploaded to the service as a body parameter after base64 encoding. It works normally in most cases. Today I came across a request, its size is about 6M, every time nginx will report "upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed". Blow is the nginx errorlog.

So I use wireshark to capture the packets, I found that there is a one minute gap between two network packets, it may be the reason, but I don't know how to explain that. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Wireshark picture:
[image: wireshark picture]

nginx error log:

`````
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 http upstream dummy handler
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: worker cycle
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: select event: fd:560 wr:0
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: select event: fd:608 wr:0
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: select event: fd:616 wr:0
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: select timer: 57
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: select ready 0
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: timer delta: 63
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 event timer del: 616: 548607287
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 http upstream request: "/xxx/yyy?"
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 http upstream process upstream
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [error] 24844#25224: *115 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /xxx/yyy HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9099/xxx/yyy", host: "localhost:80"
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 http upstream exit: 00000000
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 finalize http upstream request: 502
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 finalize http proxy request
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 free rr peer 1 0
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 close http upstream connection: 616
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 free: 02B7D598, unused: 88
2021/09/26 14:02:59 [debug] 24844#25224: *115 select del event fd:616 ev:768````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase `proxy_read_timeout`

`proxy_read_timeout 300;`

Comment: thanks, it worked. But it took 60s to respond, and I still don’t understand why it took so long.

Comment: nice, it's probably the upstream server taking so long, can you mark this as the answer